# Alter date into text based on month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to take a date from one column and convert it to a string into a new column. The capitalization would depend on if the month is June or July. (These are the only two months shown) I tried using the date_format() function but wasn't able to have much success with it.

```
invoice_date | month_due
2014-07-20   | Due in July 2014
2014-06-30   | DUE IN JUNE 2014
```

Comment: You don't give plenty of information. What about if the month is January or February for example?

Comment: @ekalyvio it only lists June and July

Answer (score 1):

Based on your very little information you are giving, I would suggest the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    invoice_date,
    CASE MONTH(invoice_date)
        WHEN 6 THEN CONCAT("DUE IN JUNE ", CONVERT(YEAR(invoice_date), char))
        WHEN 7 THEN CONCAT("Due in July ", CONVERT(YEAR(invoice_date), char))
        ELSE "SOME OTHER MONTH"
    END month_due
FROM invoice
```

Here, I suppose the table name is invoice. In any case the month is anything other than 6 or 7 it will display "SOME OTHER MONTH".